# My application works perfectly local but not in the remote server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, class-design, remote-server, object-reference, class-designer

When I upload the files on the remote server I get the following message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

And a few errors supposed to be happening in the ClassDesigner file and other few classes.

Comment: Please give more details of the exceptions.

Comment: There was no error in the code, but thanks anyway. The problem was that someone else deleted a table on the database. The cause for this were some models that were not used. Thanks anyway for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you give is to general to help. It basically means you are trying to access a object that is null. Please at least give a stack trace.

Comment: I'm sorry... Here is the stack trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Models.ClasesDataContext..ctor() in Clases.designer.cs:98 
[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0

Comment: System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Summumnet.Controllers.PortalController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +189

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +47

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +13
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8677954
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: As I said before, in my local computer it works perfectly, no errors compiling... don't understand what happens remotely. Also, I tried two different ways to publish the app but no success... Don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code.

You need to read the details of the exceptions and find and fix the bug.